# xampp not working with DynDNS

Tags: apache, dns, localhost, xampp

My setup consists of:

- a XAMPP 1.7.7 installation, with Apache configured to listen to port `8080`
- dyn.com to make the projects accessible from the web ( `8080` shows up as 'open' when checking with http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports )
- various PHP/Ajax/etc projects stored in folders inside `xampp/htdocs`. Ex: `xampp/htdocs/crypt`
- the `xampp` folder, phpMyAdmin and MySQL are password-protected

When trying to access any of the projects using dyn.dns URLs ( `http://mydomain.dyndns-ip.com/crypt` ), I get a web page with something like

> Object Not Found
>   The requested URL '/crypt' was not found on the RomPager server.

Adding the port number ( `http://mydomain.dyndns-ip.com:8080/crypt` ) will result in "The connection has timed out" pages.
*However*, all the projects work when loaded with a localhost URL ( `http://localhost:8080/crypt/` ).

Other issues:

- accessing the root dyn.com URL asks me to log in to my router
- when clicking the "Admin" button for Apache on the XAMPP control panel, it opens `http://localhost/xampp/` - instead of `http://localhost:8080/xampp/`

I think this might have something to do with password-protecting the `xampp` folder,
but there doesn't seem to any automatic way of "undo"-ing the security changes,
and I don't know how to do that manually. Any pointers in troubleshooting this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: RomPager is an embeddable web server used in your router - so there is a misconfiguration that is returning your router admin by default.

Answer (score 1):

Often, port 8080 is the remote management port for your router. If you're getting a router login page when you go to your Dyn hostname, I'd suggest changing either the remote management port or the port your webserver runs on.

Also, AFAIK Dyn doesn't do port forwarding so accessing `http://mydomain.dyndns-ip.com/crypt` will use port 80.

Why not host your webserver on 80?

Comment: strangely enough, remote management is not enabled; the settings the same as in [this picture](http://screenshots.portforward.com/Dlink/DSL-2680/Remote_Management.htm), I shouldn't be able to even see the router config pages. WAN Management (TR-069) was enabled, however; but disabling it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I also tried changing the port to `80`. I didn't get a timeout, as with `8080`, but instead received the "URL was not found on the RomPager server" error page. I also noticed the port not displayed in the address bar, probably because it's the default anyway.